# Procedure em Package receber um array (vindo de um cursor/função) como parâmetro de input - Oracle

Tags: oracle, input, pl-sql, packages

Boa tarde,

já tenho uma certa experiencia com PL/SQL mas comecei agora a trabalhar com o banco oracle e packages.

Estou com um problema do qual a minha procedure na package está recebendo dois parametros e a partir dele executando algumas tarefas trabalhando com o bulk collect, forall e rowtype para buscar as informações em várias tabelas.

A questão é: eu preciso que esses parametros venham de uma outra função ou cursor e a partir desse retorno, execute a minha procedure dentro da package.
Esse cursor/função precisa estar dentro da mesma package também.

Esse cursor/função irá consultar uma tabela X e se nessa tabela contiver alguns resultados, os mesmos irão buscar a partir da procedure a informação necessária e inseri-las em uma tabela temporária que será consumida por outro processo.

Alguém já trabalhou com isso ou sabe mais ou menos o caminho que eu possa realizar isso?

Obrigada

Comment: Veja se entendi a sua pergunta ... Você quer uma função que retorne uma coleção, este valor deve ser enviado por parâmetro para seu procedimento, que vai processar as informações e realizar a efetivação em banco. É este o fluxo desejado?

Comment: Isso! exatamente

Answer (score 1):

É possível criar uma função com o retorno da Type da sua coleção, no procedimento que deseja receber esta coleção será necessário passar por parâmetro o mesmo tipo (Se precisar manipular os dados da coleção será necessário ser um parâmetro IN OUT).

Segue um exemplo similar ao que foi solicitado (no final tem um link com a criação das tabelas e consulta usados no exemplo):

```
create or replace package PCK_TESTE is

  Type TPessoas is table of pessoas%Rowtype;

  Function fRetornaPessoas return TPessoas;

  Procedure PreencheTabelaTemporaria(aPessoas IN OUT TPessoas );

end PCK_TESTE;
/
create or replace package body PCK_TESTE is

  Function fRetornaPessoas return TPessoas is
    vRetorno TPessoas; 
    cursor TodasPessoas is
      select * from pessoas;
  begin
    -- Carrega coleção e retorna  
    open TodasPessoas;
    fetch TodasPessoas bulk collect into vRetorno;
    close TodasPessoas;

    return vRetorno;
  end;

  Procedure PreencheTabelaTemporaria( aPessoas IN OUT TPessoas ) is
  begin
    --Exemplo de regra de negócio 
    for i in aPessoas.first .. aPessoas.last loop
      aPessoas(i).nome := aPessoas(i).nome || ' Sobrenome não informado';
    end loop;
    --Efetivação na tabela temporária
    forall i in aPessoas.First .. aPessoas.Last
      insert into TMPpessoas (id, nome, Data_Nascimento) values (aPessoas(i).id, aPessoas(i).nome, aPessoas(i).Data_Nascimento);
  end;

end PCK_TESTE;
/
```

Chamada do método:

```
declare
  vPessoa PCK_TESTE.TPessoas;
begin
  vPessoa := pck_teste.fRetornaPessoas();
  pck_teste.preenchetabelatemporaria(vPessoa);
end;
```

Exemplos com dados no SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bed69/1/0